# Nuxt.js: Global mixin only working on the Server-Side

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am creating an application using Nuxt.js. I have a function that I need to use a lot in my application called `isAuthneticated`. Below is the function:

`~/mixins/auth.js`

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    isAuthenticated() {
      // make sure that user is logged in
      if (this.$store.state.auth.user) {
        this.user = this.$store.state.auth.user
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }
  },
}
```

As you can see I am exporting it as a computed property to another file which will register it as a global mixin, here's the code for that file:

`~/plugins/mixins.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

import auth from '~/mixins/auth'

Vue.mixin(auth)
```

I registered this plugin using the `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
plugins: ['~/plugins/mixins']
```

Now If I try to use `isAuthenticated` in my template, I get the following error in the browser console:

```sh
Property or method "isAuthenticated" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

But if I use the `created` hook on the mixin object and log something, it gets logged successfully in the terminal, rather than the console as `created` is run on the server-side.

My question is: Why isn't this working? Why is `isAuthenticated` `undefined`?

Any help would be appreciated!!!

### Edit 1:

This is the code of the component that tries to use this computed property:

```html
<template v-if="!isAuthenticated">
      <nuxt-link to="/register">
        <v-btn outlined color="primary" class="d-none d-md-flex mx-2">Sign Up</v-btn>
      </nuxt-link>
      <nuxt-link to="/login">
        <v-btn depressed color="primary" class="d-none d-md-flex mx-2">Login</v-btn>
      </nuxt-link>
    </template>
```

Comment: I tried this on my local system. It was working. Can you share your folder structure and the code of the component that uses `isAuthenticated`?

Comment: This maybe unrelated, but, writing `v-if` on `<template>` does not work in VueJS. You need to add a parent `<div>` and add your `v-if` on it.

Comment: Is it possible for you to push your code to a repo which can be cloned or maybe you could create a working JSFiddle where this is happening.